# Error con clase TimePickerDialoG: Cannot resolve constructor 'TimePickerDialog(android.content.context,int,int,boolean)'

Tags: android

Teniendo el siguiente código, he solucionado un problema.

clase app

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

public class App extends Application {

    private static Application myApplication;

    public static Application getApplication() {
        Application sApplication = new Application();
        return sApplication;
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return getApplication().getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        myApplication = this;
    }
}
```

newInstance dentro de fragmento.

```
   public static Categories newInstance(int index,CheckBox check) {
    Categories categories = new Categories();
    java.util.Calendar now = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();

    TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(
            App.getContext(),
            now.get(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            now.get(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE),
            check.isChecked()


    );
```

Pero ahora tengo el inconveniente de que al momento de llamar de esta manera al context   App.getContext() al momento de pasar los parametros, me muestra el siguiente error :

Cannot resolve constructor 'TimePickerDialog(android.content.context,int,int,boolean)'

OJO lo llamo de esta manera porque si utilizo this,getContext() o Categories.this me dice que no se puede referenciar un context dentro de un metodo static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al ver la documentación de [los constructores de `TimePickerDialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html#pubctors) puedes ver que efectivamente no existe un constructor que acepte esos argumentos. Existen dos constructores para dicha clase:

```
TimePickerDialog(Context, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener, int, int, boolean)

TimePickerDialog(Context, int, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener, int, int, boolean)
```

Por lo visto, quieres utilizar el primer constructor, por lo cual te faltaría el argumento de tipo `TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener`. Agrega este argumento y tu código podrá compilar.